# Как в вордпресс вывести тэги определенной категории?

Tags: wordpress

На сайте на вордпресс тэги выводятся с помощью функции wp_tag_cloud().
Как можно вывести тэги только определенной категории, 
чтобы на странице каждой категории были свои тэги?

Comment: у тэгов нет категорий. 
тэг, категория - это две встроеные таксономии в вордпрессе
может вам нужно найти все посты в определенной категории, а затем уже все тэги этих постов ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вам уже написали, категории и рубрики - это разные таксономии, которые завязаны на главной таксономии "посты". Единственный вариант реализации, который я вижу, следующий:

1) получаем текущую категорию;
 2) получаем все посты из этой категории;
 3) в массив получаем все теги этих постов;
 4) проходим по массиву и удаляем дубли;
 5) выводим массив тегов.

Если хотите - могу написать код, но сразу предупреждаю, что это хороший вариант только при условии, что у вас не много постов, как только постов становится много, ваш сервер начнет нагибаться... 
Задумайтесь, насколько вам нужен такой вариант.

Comment: Был бы благодарен за код. Поделюсь соткой своего рейтинга. Хочу просто понять, как это реализовать.